# Query text from database to display in TextView but Text isn't in order

Tags: android, database, textview

I queried text(title) from database and I display it in TextView but when it displays, it isn't in order, but it just displays one title and that title is in the last index of the title column.

how can I display it all and order from first to last?

ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    Cursor cursor = dataSource.database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+CafeDbOpenHelper.TABLE_CAFE, null);

    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        context = c;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();           
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(converView == null){
            converView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        }
        viewHolder.imageview = (ImageView) converView.findViewById(R.id.imv_card_cafe);
        viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);


        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.i("db", " return "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TAG_CAFE_TITLE)));
                viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TAG_CAFE_TITLE)));
        }


        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/downloadedfile.png";   
        viewHolder.imageview.setImageResource(mThumb[position]);

        return converView;
    }
}
```

Logcat db tag is the text from database

```
03-04 14:44:00.411: D/AbsListView(22842): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-04 14:44:00.426: I/ACTION(22842): Database is open
03-04 14:44:00.442: I/number(22842): return11 rows
03-04 14:44:00.450: I/ACTION(22842): Database is open
03-04 14:44:00.504: I/db(22842):  return Kiriya Café
03-04 14:44:00.504: I/db(22842):  return Brown Coffee and Bakery
03-04 14:44:00.504: I/db(22842):  return The Blue Pumpkin - Riverside
03-04 14:44:00.504: I/db(22842):  return Black Canyon Coffee
03-04 14:44:00.559: D/libEGL(22842): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-04 14:44:00.575: D/libEGL(22842): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-04 14:44:00.575: D/libEGL(22842): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-04 14:44:00.684: D/OpenGLRenderer(22842): Enabling debug mode 0
03-04 14:45:35.348: I/ACTION(22842): Database is close
```

Image

[image]

Comment: how many string you are getting form db ?

Comment: I query it all. all string

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the order of the titles, you can just modify your select query so that it retrieves the rows already ordered:

```
"SELECT * FROM "+CafeDbOpenHelper.TABLE_CAFE + " ORDER BY YOUR_COLUMN_TITLE", null
```

Now as for why only a single textview is being shown, it has to do with how you are writing your logic:

```
viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);


while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
      Log.i("db", " return "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TAG_CAFE_TITLE)));
      viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TAG_CAFE_TITLE)));
}
```

You are basically modifying the same textview four times in that loop, so it naturally gets set to the last one you retrieved from the database (Which happens to be Black Canyon Coffee)

You need to either 1)Dynamically create the textview and add it to your existing view or 2)Create four textviews placed in your layout and set them appropriately in your while loop.

Edit: Generally, you will want to go with Option #1 because it's indisputably the most sensible approach when you are working with a consistently changing database (and also for the ease of future modifications). If however, you are absolutely certain in your project specification that you are going to have a fixed number of rows in your table (because you can only have four cafes in your app for instance and you will only swap the tables for loading different names), then the quick and dirty way is to make four textviews and set each textviews appropriately by iterating them.

This answer is given mostly out of speculation because you didn't tell us how you intend to use/manipulate the database, so it's entirely up to your judgement.

Comment: @Obl Tobl The latter option assumes that he has four items fixed in the database, in which creating four textviews is a logical answer. This is exactly why I laid out two options, first one being dynamically creating the textviews. Don't just downvote because I presented several options as the author didn't provide the full context.

Comment: @OblTobl There is a distinct possibility that there are 4 fixed number of textviews but he is using different versions of databases or tables, each loaded with different strings. I do agree that it's very unusual to store a fixed number of data in a database like that and this possibility is very unlikely but like I said, from the fact that the OP didn't provide any context with how he's using the database, all that could be done is speculation.

Comment: Regarding the downvote, all you are doing is just appending text retrieved from cursor to the existing textview via loop. Would you think it's practical to show a single line of text fixed on that single textview? Imagine how it would look. Of course, I'm very much speculating here as well but since you are doing the same thing, I don't really see a reason not to especially when I have clearly stated the alternative and better way to go about it.

Comment: Because like I said, I do not know for sure what he is doing. What if he really did want to use the database that way with fixed number of rows? Of course, the OP should've expressed this preferably speaking. But since he didn't, I simply left an option that actually might work for his purposes. It's entirely up to the asker to determine what works for him.

Comment: That gives me an indication that he wants to retrieve the ordered rows from the database and then update the textview. It doesn't give me any indication on how exactly he **intended** to use the database.

Comment: @OblTobl It's entirely up to you to remove the downvote or not, freely being able to vote and anonymity are two very important virtues of SO, although the former part is more or less irrelevant here now. This question is essentially impossible to answer correctly in its current form anyways, and all I wanted to do is present a list of opportunities that doesn't deviate from the scope much. I will go ahead and update the answer anyways to avoid any further confusion.

Comment: sorry, but this is a problem of SO, because your are NOT able to vote freely. In my opinion you won't have downvoted my answer if i haven't downvoted yours. and in my opinion this is just an act of revenge. i also will remove the downvote, even if i think that this is an answer not helping anybody on SO and maybe even helps to confuse beginners. but nevertheless i don't want to argue with you about such things.

Comment: @OblTobl I think that's just a matter of perspective, but I agree, we should leave the case as is.